# PHP-Error in constant string

Tags: php, unset

I suddenly get an error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in the following line:

```
unset('SCAN/DATA.FIL');
```

I don't see the Error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unset()` unsets variables. You can't [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) a string literal, that doesn't make sense.

Perhaps you are looking for [`unlink()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)?

Answer (score 1):

you can't unset a constant. If you want to delete the file, your function of choice it [unlink()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unlink.php).

Comment: Yeah, I got that already...thanks for that REALLY fast answer!

Comment: you're welcome - if it helped, could you sign my answer as solution (or the one from NullUserException, which ias basically the same)?